# Django: add model fields to list_display and display related values per entry

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following model definitions, see below.

models.py:

```
class Userstatus(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.CharField(...)


class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    visibility = models.ManyToManyField(Userstatus)
```

admin.py:

```
class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', )

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

In the admin list view of "Foo" via FooAdmin the list_display list should include the "label"s from Userstatus so a column for each label will appear. I could create and call a method that creates the list for list_display.

But then no properties or callables actually exist that would allow me to return let's say a boolean for each label column, based on the visibility-many-to-many field.

What are my options? Should I try to intercept a callable or attribute request to Foo and create a boolean result on the fly? (Hitting the DB too often or making the columns sortable is another problem, but first things first).

Comment: Can you give more details about what a "boolean based on the visibility field" would look like?

Comment: I want to dynamically add columns to the list view (=list_display). The columns are essentially the contents of the "label" CharFields in "Userstatus". If a certain Foo item has references on say two labels "A" and "B" I will visualize that reference with a boolean attribute and let Django use it's fancy "on" and "off" icons, like in the admin site documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/) says ...

> ManyToManyField fields aren't supported, because that would entail
>   executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you
>   want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add
>   that method's name to list_display. (See below for more on custom
>   methods in list_display.)

Comment: I know that part. But I have to construct the list_display-list dynamically based on the values of another model. In theory if I could ad the same custom method with a parameter that would be fine. But AFAIK that is not possible.

Comment: If you need a column for every status, then I guess you need a custom method on the FOO model for every Userstatus.  Will there be a fixed number of Userstatuses or at least a maximum number of them?

Comment: If the number of items is known and fixed I could use the CHOICE tupel approach and custom methods, but that's no option.

Comment: I also thought about that one column that simply computes the statuses - as a last resort. Sorting wouldn't work then (well, it wouldn't work out of the box here either, as mentioned) and a list_filter for statuses is not that informative here.

Comment: How about creating a completely custom view and template?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want Userstatus to be a database table and not just a list of a few statuses that could be accessed through a "choices" tuple?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. A static choice tupel is no option in my situation.